# Indirect speech: If Pres.Perf. becomes Past Perf. and Past Simple also becomes Past Perf. What was in direct sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, reported-speech

Could you please help me to realize the reverse operation. If Pres.Perf. becomes Past Perf. and Past Simple also becomes Past Perf. how can I define what was in direct speech?

For example: Indirect speech: *"Bill asked Mary if she had done anything the previous weekend."*

Which form was right for direct speech:

- 1) Have you done anything last weekend?
- 2) Did you do anything last weekend?

Comment: Why the doubt? What do you think would the natural answer be?

Comment: I'm not native. I don't know which form is natural. In russian both forms sounds correct: 1) "Ты что-нибудь сделала на выходных?" и 2) "Ты что-нибудь делала на выходных?". The difference only in "success" of doing (was Mary succeeded in her doing or she just had a process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a time of the action, so it is the second option: "did you do anything last week".

Comment: But that is the only way you can tell. In general, there's no difference: "Bill asked Mary if she had seen the book" can equally well correspond to "Did you see the book?" or "Have you seen the book?"

Comment: Why do you think so?